# Using `diff` from R via `system(..)`

Tags: r, string, bash, diff

I was willing to compare two paths (named `a` and `b`) in `R` using the `diff` command from `Bash`.

In bash I would do

```
$ a=Path/to/foo/directory/
$ b=Path/to/bar/directory/
$ diff <(printf ${a} | tr / '\n') <(printf ${b} | tr / '\n')
3c3
< foo
---
> bar
```

So from R I am trying

```
a="Path/to/foo/directory/"
b="Path/to/bar/directory/"
system(
  paste0(
    "a=",a,
    ";b=",b,
    ";diff <(printf ${a} | tr / '\n') <(printf ${b} | tr / '\n')"
  )
)
```

OR

```
system(
    paste0(
      "diff <(printf ",a," | tr / '\n') <(printf ",b," | tr / '\n')"
    )
  )
```

but both return an error.

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `a=Path/to/foo/directory/;b=Path/to/bar/directory/;diff <(printf ${a} | tr / ''
```

even though copy-pasting the output of the `paste0` function into bash works fine.

There might be better ways to compare strings in R and I would welcome alternative solutions. However, I am particularly interested in understanding what is going wrong with my usage of the `system()` function and how to solve it.

Comment: I don't think `/bin/sh` supports the `<(` process substitution that you can get to work in `bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150367/terminal-vs-system-in-r?noredirect=1#39150441), `system(..)` is not running `/usr/bin/bash` but `/usr/bin/sh`. Here are two possible solutions to the problem.

**Solution in "usr/bin/sh"**

So in order to make a script that run through `/usr/bin/sh` I had to print strings on files.

```
DiffPath = function(a,b,ManipulationFolder="~")
{
  if (file.exists(ManipulationFolder))
  {
  system(
    paste0(
      "cd ",ManipulationFolder,
      ";a=",a,
      ";b=",b,
      ";printf ${a} | tr / '\n' > a.txt",
      ";printf ${b} | tr / '\n' > b.txt",
      ";diff a.txt b.txt",
      ";rm a.txt;rm b.txt"
    )
  ) 
  } else
  {
    warning(paste0("Cannot find the ManipulationFolder ( ",ManipulationFolder," )"))
  }
}
```

**Solution in "usr/bin/bash"**

An alternative and nicer solution is to explicitly give the command to bash.

```
DiffPath = function(a,b)
{
  system(
    paste0(
      'bash -c \'diff <(printf ',a,' | tr / "\n") <(printf ',b,' | tr / "\n")\''
    )
  ) 
}
```

**Function call**

```
a="Path/to/foo/directory/"
b="Path/to/bar/directory/"

DiffPath(a,b)
3c3
< foo
---
> bar
```