# `Terminal` vs `system()` in R

Tags: r, bash, macos

I tried running the following in R

```
system("Message=HelloWoRld;echo $(sed 's/R/r/' <(echo ${Message}))")
```

but it fails, while

```
Message=HelloWoRld
echo $(sed 's/R/r/' <(echo ${Message}))
```

works fine when copy pasted in the terminal. The issue seems related to `<(..)`. When I do either `which bash` or `system("which bash")`, I get `/bin/bash`.

**Why does the same command via `system()` or directly on the terminal window does not yield to the same output?**

---

FYI, I am on `Mac OS X 10.11.3`. Bash is `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)` and R is `R version 3.2.3`.

Comment: Didn't realize that your where wrapping your prev Q in another environment. Try pipes, instead of process sub, ie. `system("Message=HelloWoRld;echo $(echo ${Message} | sed 's/R/r/' ")` . Good luck.

Comment: The outer `echo` is redundant; `system("Message=HelloWoRld; echo $Message | sed 's/R/r/'")`.

Comment: @shellter That will have the same problem as OP’s current code (i.e. it won’t work either — depending on the shell). In fact, both solutions are terribly indirect. Much more direct is `sed s/R/r/ <<< $Message`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `<<<` will fail for the same reason `<(...)` fails.

Comment: @chepner Of course. But my answer solves that. Or are you saying that shellter’s solution would work on `/bin/sh`? Is `$(…)` command substitution POSIX compliant?

Comment: Using a pipe is no more indirect than wrapping a command in a string to pass to another shell for execution.

Comment: @shellter (but for all the others too): the main point of my previous question was to be able to create a simple code that would fail in system("..") but not in bash in order to ask the current question. I figured out `echo ${Message} | sed 's/R/r/'` is an easy alternative. Thanks!

Comment: @chepner . Doah, I need to re-read my code before going away. Yep, leading `echo` was completely redundant! Thanks and good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter My final goal through these two questions (which is now achieved) was to answer my own question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128344/using-diff-from-r-via-system).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`system` is not a terminal emulator, and it’s not running Bash. Your terminal runs Bash. To get the same effect with `system`, run the command inside Bash. E.g.

```
system('bash -c \'echo $(date)\'')
```

What’s more, your current Bash command is quite convoluted and uses unnecessary command invocations; you can achieve the same via the much simpler

```
sed s/R/r/ <<< $Message
```

@chepner makes the excellent point that another solution can be used directly in `system` without need to pass execution to Bash:

```
system("Message=HelloWoRld; echo $Message | sed 's/R/r/'")
```

Comment: Indeed the following would work `system('bash -c \'Message=HelloWoRld;echo $(sed "s/R/r/" <(echo ${Message}))\'')`. So what language should one input in `system("..")`? It is some kind of shell script? Is there a `/usr/bin/<something>` that is the language used by `system(..)`? Thank you

Comment: @Remi.b It depends on your system, see the `system` documentation for details. On Mac, the command is probably run through `/bin/sh` but I wouldn’t rely on that as a general rule. In particular, this will never work on Windows, by design.

Comment: All POSIX-compliant systems use `/bin/sh` as their default shell; the actual shell used to implement `/bin/sh` is generally irrelevant, as long as the shell executes its input in a POSIX-compliant fashion.